# Android ActionBar compatibility: MenuItem.setActionView(View)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, compatibility, android-menu

I'm using the appcompat7 lib for ActionBar backwards compatibility. Now I have a `MenuItem` that I retrieve, and then want to set an `ImageView myView` as its icon.

The way how to do it from API level 11 is:

```
MenuItem menuItemRefresh = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
menuItemRefresh.setActionView(myView);
```

For API levels lower than 11 this doesn't work, the second line will show an error. Is there an option to do this in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Look at `MenuItemCompat`: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html

There is a static function `setActionView(MenuItem item, View view)`

So your code should look like:

```
MenuItem menuItemRefresh = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
menuItemRefresh = MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menuItemRefresh, myView);
```