# MenuItem.setActionView() doesn't work

Tags: android, menuitem, android-menu

I'm trying to make actionbar menu with custom item view programatically.

My `menu.xml` file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_category"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_category"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/category">
        <menu>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Creation of menu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem category = menu.findItem(R.id.action_category);
    Menu categoriesMenu = category.getSubMenu();
    Category[] items = Category.values();

    LayoutInflater baseInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i){
        Category c = items[i];
        MenuItem item = categoriesMenu.add(i, c.id, 0, c.resourceText);

        View myCustomView = baseInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list_item, null);
        ((ImageView)myCustomView.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(c.resourceIcon);

        item.setActionView(myCustomView);
    }
}
```

But `setActionView()` doesn't work. Just standard text only item is created. Does anyone know how to create menu item with custom layout programatically?

Comment: I see you call getActivity(), so I suppose you are using this code in your Fragment. Do you enable menu in Fragment via `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` method?

Comment: Yes, menu is created but with default item view, not custom.

Comment: Just adding one more point here. We don't have to inflate the action view ourselves in all scenarios. Just pass the layout id to `menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.your_action_view)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation it appears `setActionView` returns a MenuItem itself, so it's not manipulating the existing item but returning a new item with that action view. - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView(android.view.View)

Since it's returning a whole new MenuItem, you could try creating it and calling setActionView *before* you add it to your collection?

*EDIT*: This was a poor assumption to assume just because an item was returned that no manipulation happened. See Renetik's comment below.

Comment: Thanks for response! Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work either. And it seems that there's no big difference between yours and mine snippets, because I don't manipulate `MenuItem` after `setActionView` is called.

Comment: @mol Good point, I'm rethinking this now. Do you understand what I meant in the first paragraph, though? The `setActionView()` returns a new menu item, not manipulate it, so perhaps that should be called *before* you add it to the category?

Comment: Yes, I understood. The thing is that `Menu` doesn't have `add()` method with `MenuItem` as a parameter.

Comment: @mol Gah, I thought I was on to something. What API? Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402912/android-actionbar-compatibility-menuitem-setactionviewview

Comment: MenuItemImpl in android source is setting action view and notifying changes to menu, you make assumption that because menu item us returned, its new menu item. Its normal for methods to return this for chaining purposes...

Comment: Ooo that's a really good call out thanks for that @Renetik. I added a little note to my answer.